# Синхронизация Github и Intellij Idea на mac os

Tags: java, intellij-idea, github, macos

Всем привет,проблема следующая. Я установил Git и учебную версию IntelliJ idea на свой ноут (mac os), захотел опубликовать свой код на своем репозитории, однако вместо моего кода в функции main публикуется стандартный автогенерируемый код. Причем такая проблема у меня не наблюдается в pycharm. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в чем проблема и какие существуют методы решения?
**Ниже привожу пример моего кода:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double a = 3.6;
        double b = 4.1;
        double c = 5.9;
        double result = a*b*c;
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

'''

**Код который оказывается на репозитории:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Вот сама ссылка на репозиторий:
https://github.com/julianpodruhin/Task_1_4_1/tree/master/src

Comment: Может вы просто комит забываете делать?

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!